# navigating from UINavigationVController presented Modally to the root UINavigationVController - swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

As shown in this picture, I have root navigation controller which has its root viewcontroller as VC1.

In VC2 i present Modally with the option: **Over Current Context** in order to get the Blur effect.

In VC4, User has the option to **navigation back to the root viewcontorller VC1**. which is shown in the large Red Arrow.

[image: explain]

I tried 2 ways:

### First:

**In VC4:**

```
func popToRoot(){
    self.dismiss()
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: animated)
}
```

**The Problem:** This code navigation back to VC2.

### Second:

I tried to have a `public static boolean` which i set it true if user wants to go back to `VC1`

**VC1:**

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    public static var shouldGoBackToMainRoot = false;

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        VC1.shouldGoBackToMainRoot = false
    }    
}
```

**VC2:**

```
class VC2: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if VC1.shouldGoBackToMainRoot {
            self.dismiss()
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: animated)
            return
        }
    }    
}
```

**VC4:**

```
class VC4: UIViewController {
    // .. other code ...

    func onGoBackToRootClicked() {
        VC1.shouldGoBackToMainRoot = true
        self.dismiss()
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: animated)
    }
}
```

**The Problem:** In `VC2`: `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` will not get called since i presented `VC3` with `Over Current Context`.

**NOTE:** Removing Over Current Context will let `VC2`'s viewDidAppear function to get called, but i will lose the Blur effect. which is not what i want.

**Question:** How to navigate from VC4 to VC1 without losing the Blur effect ?

Comment: check this for unWind segue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not present VC3 on VC2 instead of this just present it overCurrentContext on `self.window.rootViewController` in `AppDelegate`
And make a strong reference of your `firstNavigationController` in `AppDelegate`
So in your VC4 when you want to go back to VC1 all you have to do is...

```
let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
delegate.rootNavigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

This is remove a viewController from your bottomNavigationStack that is under the VC4 and will not remove the VC4 from the top.

Answer (score 1):

Write a delegate from VC4 to VC2. In VC2 dismiss the presented navigation controller. On completion of dismiss operation, then use popToRootViewController to navigate back to VC1.